# django rest framework: set field-level error from serializer validate() method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have a serializer that validates fields based on the values of other fields, In the error response I would like to show each field error as a field error as opposed to showing everything under "non_field_errors" which is what would happen if I were to raise a ValidationError in the object-level validate method. Below is an illustration of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    ...
    def validate(self, data):
        field_val1 = data['field_val1']
        field_val2 = data['field_val2']
        if not self._is_field_valid(field_val1, field_val2):
            # The below line is how I would do what I want with Django
            # Forms, however, it's not valid in DRF
            self._errors['field_val1'] = 'this field is not valid'
```

The desired error response is:

```
{'field_val1': ['this field is not valid']}
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I figured it out, on [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) page of the documentation in the "BaseSerializer" section, there's an example that shows ValidationError can take a dictionary argument upon initialization.

If I `raise ValidationError({'field_val1': ['this field is not valid']})` I get the JSON response I want.

Comment: Also works well to mimic 'This field is required' responses.

Comment: @MarkMishyn no need to, but it's convention set by Django and followed by Rest Framework for fields errors to be lists of errors. But its up to your frontend/client logic to actually decide how to support them.

Comment: Note that by doing this you also have to handle translation yourself, unlike @frnhr's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Similarly to the answer by @Jkk.jonah, this raises a `ValidationError`, but it reuses the original exception text without need to re-implement translations:

```
try:
    serializer.fields['field_val1'].fail('required')
except ValidationError as exc:
    raise ValidationError({
        'field_val1': exc.detail,
    })
```

By default (i.e. on `rest_framework.fields.Field` class), available keys are:

```
default_error_messages = {
    'required': _('This field is required.'),
    'null': _('This field may not be null.')
}
```

Subclasses can add their own error messages there (and `Serializer` is a subclass of `Field`).

BTW, new error messages will be automagically merged with existing (inherited) messages - won't be overridden as might be expected.

Comment: Using the built-in error messages is great for me because the translation is already there.

Answer (score 1):

If you have logic that applies to all the fields, you can still get the desired result by doing this:

```
def validate(self, data):
    for key, value in data.items():
        # checks if value is empty
        if not value:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({key: "This field should not be left empty."})

    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using built-in validators in DRF (which are in-fact django core validators) you have to preprocess django ValidationError coming from validator  with a function `get_error_detail` drf is using for this purpose.

```
def _validate_min_value(self, data, key):
        try:
            MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.01'))(data.get(key))
        except ValidationErrorDjango as exc:
            raise ValidationError(
                {key: get_error_detail(exc)}
            )
```

Note that ValidationErrorDjango is a ValidationError from `django.core.exceptions`, while ValidationError is a one from `rest_framework.exceptions`