# Django Rest Framework - conditionally make serializer's field required or not using other field value

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

In my DRF project, I have a model:

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    PRIVATE = 'PRIVATE'
    COMPANY = 'COMPANY'
    ACCOUNT_TYPES = (
        (PRIVATE, _('Private')),
        (COMPANY, _('Company')),
    )
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
    person_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
    account_type = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=ACCOUNT_TYPES)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
```

and ItemSerializer in serializers like:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('account_type', 'company_name', 'person_name')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print('ItemSerializer, create')
        print('validated_data:', validated_data)
        return super().create(validated_data)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        print('ItemSerializer validate, attrs:', attrs)
        return attrs
```

as you can see in the model, there are fields `company_name` and `person_name`, none of them is required in the model.

To create an Item, `account_type` has to be specified. Its either `PRIVATE` or `COMPANY`.

Now, in my serializer I want to make specific fields required if account type is company or private. For example, is account_type is `COMPANY`, I want to make field `company_name` required. If account_type is `PRIVATE` I want  to make `person_name` required.

1. Which method is a proper space to achieve this and how can I do this?
2. Also using above logic I want to do extra validation on the field. Example: is `account_type` is `PRIVATE` and person_name is not empty, I want to do some validation on `person_name` (check if it has a proper format, length etc)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `def validate(self, data)` to check **condition required**,
and `def validate_{field_name}(self, value)` for extra validation:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('account_type', 'company_name', 'person_name')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'company_name': {'required': False},
            'person_name': {'required': False},
        }

    def validate(self, data):
        data_dict = dict(data)
        data_keys = data.keys()
        account_type= data_dict.get('account_type')
        if account_type == 'PRIVATE' and 'person_name' not in data_keys:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('person_name required when account_type is PRIVATE.')
        if account_type == 'COMPANY' and 'company_name' not in data_keys:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('company_name required when account_type is COMPANY.')
        return data

    def validate_person_name(self, value):
        if len(value) < 10:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('person_name must be at least 10 characters.')
        return value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `validate` method of the serializer that receives all the serialized fields as parameter, see [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation).

Comment: It doesn't say how can I mark a specific fields as required.

Comment: At that level, it's up to you to add the logic.  Raise `serializers.ValidationError` if the requirement is not met.

Comment: I think that it is not possible to mark the fields as required conditionally, in the `validate` method you could check if the field is present and if it is not, you could raise a `ValidationError` with the appropiate message. Another solution would be to use 2 different serializers, one for `PRIVATE` and another for `COMPANY`.

Comment: @piedra If I raise a ValidationError in validate method, error will be listed as "non_field_errors" - I want to have an error message tied to a field.

Comment: @dease https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28179619/django-rest-framework-set-field-level-error-from-serializer-validate-method

Answer (score 0):

You could define two serializers `PrivateSerializer` and `CompanySerializer` then at your view, use the method `.get_serializer_class()` and depending on what's being sent in the request you return one or the other.

This way you define each serializer validations depending on the case.